# mysql column default value 0 saves as NULL

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database with a `TINYINT(4)` column that previously had no value set to default, and I assume `null` was being set as the default value. I had to manually push '0' into the database saving logic every time in my code, so I have now updated the column to instead have an explicit default value of '0'. Now when I save my data, instead `null` is being set, and throwing off my code. When I set `not null` for the column, then it throws an error due to my not passing in a value in my database saving code. I've checked all of my other entries in the table, and do not see any other 'null' values that may be throwing this off - all are either '0' or '1'.

There must be some quirk here with my database. I have the same exact column with the same logic and that is saving as '0' perfectly fine. Looking for any insight into what could be causing this.

Comment: Can you post some code from your database writing logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using a framework where objects are automatically converted into SQL statements for saving? If the value of the property in your PHP class is not set and the column is nullable then it will insert `null` instead of 0.

Consider:

```
class Foo{
    protected $propertyName;
}
```

That is equivalent in PHP to

```
class Foo{
    protected $propertyName = null;
}
```

If the `TINYINT(4)` column for `propertyName` is nullable when it builds the query to save the data it will save as `null` in the database. If you are using a design pattern like this you need set the default value in the PHP class itself. Something like

```
class Foo{
    protected $propertyName = 0;
}
```

Note, if the column is not null-able then saving the object would throw an error in this scenario. If you wanted to get fancy, you can fetch the default values for a column using

```
DESC tableName;
```

That will return information about the table, there will be a column `NULL` which will be `YES` or `NO` (describing if the column is null-able). And a column `Default` which will be the default value (or `NULL` if there is none).  You could then populate `null` fields in your class based on the default values from the database.  You would want to be careful here as there are likely some columns that should be `NULL`. Ideally, you would make any fields that can't accept `null` non-nullable and then key your logic for handling defaults only fire when the `Null` column is `NO`.

Answer (score 0):

> When inserting a new row, the default value for a column with an expression default can be inserted either by **omitting the column name** or by **specifying the column as `DEFAULT`** (just as for columns with literal defaults).
>   *source:* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

In case you specify `NULL` for the column on `INSERT` MySQL try to set the `NULL` for the column (and fails in case of `NOT NULL`). You have to ommit the column on `INSERT` or using `DEFAULT` as value on the `INSERT` statement.

[**See the following example**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=88f5dce001355a72b732a7a16b8a0d27):

```
CREATE TABLE test (
 col1 INT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
 col2 INT DEFAULT 0 NULL,
 col3 INT NULL
);

-- doesn't work since col1 can't be NULL
INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL)

-- is working: col1 is 0 after INSERT, col2 IS NULL
INSERT INTO test (col2, col3) VALUES (NULL, NULL)

-- is working: col1 is 0 after INSERT, col2 IS 0 - because using DEFAULT instead of NULL.
INSERT INTO test (col2, col3) VALUES (DEFAULT, NULL)
```